# Colors in cygwin being displayed as raw ANSI codes

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, colors, cygwin, mercurial

When running command-line Mercurial with the [color extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ColorExtension) on, the colors appear as expected in the Windows command prompt (`cmd.exe`). However, in cygwin the colors are appearing as the underlying ANSI codes (for example: `←[0;34;1m`).

When I searched for a solution, it seemed it's more common for colors to work in cygwin but not in command prompt. Have I forgotten to install something useful in cygwin that would activate display of colors?

I experience the problem on both a Windows 7 64-bit and a Vista 32-bit machine. I've tried both `bash` and `tcsh` shells. I can see colors in both shells if I do something like `ls --color`.

Comment: There is [Ansicon](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon) which brings ANSI escape code support to windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use the Cygwin console, the interpretation of control sequences is done by the Cygwin DLL. That DLL of course is only linked into Cygwin programs, so a non-Cygwin program like Mercurial will not be able to make use of that.

So why does it work when running in a cmd.exe console then, which doesn't understand control sequences in the first place? My guess would be that Mercurial uses the Windows console API when it thinks it runs in a console, and control sequences when it thinks it's running in a terminal. Perhaps that depends on whether TERM is set, so try what happens if you unset TERM.

Otherwise, try running it in a Cygwin terminal such as mintty or rxvt. There, the difference is that the control sequences are interpreted by those programs rather than the Cygwin DLL.

Answer (score 4):

In your `.hgrc` file set

```
[color]
mode = ansi
```

or

```
[color]
mode = auto
```

Comment: Thanks Dennis, I tried both but no luck.

Comment: 'mode = win32' would be the right setting there, me thinks, to tell it to use the Windows console API rather than the ANSI sequences.

Comment: Yep, that works too

Answer (score 0):

You may try this command:

```
alias ls="/bin/ls --color=auto"
```